# Postincrement in java expressions

Tags: java

In this example:

```
int i = 1;

while(i < 10)
    if(i++%2 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Why is the output `3,5,7,9` and not `2,4,6,8`?

Answer (score 4):

The condition is performed on the previous value of `i`, before it is incremented (which is even), but the output is done on the incremented value of `i` (which is odd).

Answer (score 2):

The ++ operator applied after a variable returns the value of the variable and increments the variable after the expression is evaluated. The semantic is the same than this:

```
int i = 1;
while(i < 10) { 
    boolean cond = i % 2 == 0;
    i = i + 1;
    if(cond) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The post-increment operator, uses the current value of its operand in the expression and then increments it.

We can break this down using a literal value of '2' for example. 
Basically this is what your present code is doing:

```
int i = 2;

if (i % 2 == 0) //true, 2 % 2 = 0
    i = i + 1;  //i now becomes 3
    System.out.println (i);
```

OR to make it simpler, if we remove the loop and put back your code

```
int i = 1;

if (i++ % 2 == 0) //1 % 2 != 0 

   System.out.println (i);  //Nothing will print for the if statement

   System.out.print i;  //Will print 2, because this print statement is outside
                        //the body of the if-statement
```

to get the output that you are looking for, you will have to use the prefix-increment operator (++i)

```
int i = 1;

if ( ++i % 2 == 0)  
    System.out.println (i);
```

this is equivalent to

```
 int i = 1
 if ( (i + i) % 2 == 0) //++i increments i and then uses it in the expression
      System.out.println (i);
```